# how could I use Model._meta.get.fields() to read all fields in my model

Tags: django

I want to display some fields and I know I could do it by as follows:

In models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key = True)
    date_registered = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)   
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField() 
    email = models.EmailField()
```

In my admin.py:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth' )
    fields = [('first_name' ,'last_name'), 'date_of_birth']
    pass
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

Unfortunately, my table has many fields and I do not want to write them individually. I found that `._meta.get.fields()` could read all fields. However, I can not get it correct. Using it as follows in my admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(PersonLogin)
admin.site.register(LoginHistory)

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in Person._meta.get_fields() if not field.primary_key]  
    readonly_fields = ('person_id',)
    pass

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

it says that _meta is undefined variable.

Latest Django in use.

Thank you in advance.
PG

Comment: Does `fields = '__all__'` work? I know it works for forms, not sure about admin though

Comment: nop, it says "The value of 'fields' must be a list or tuple".

Comment: Hm... Might be actually worth a ticket. I wonder how many people have a use-case for this

Comment: which django version you are using? which fields you want in list_display. There is normal datatype field, foriengkeyfield, reverse foreign key field, manytomany field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_meta` being unavailable means Django didn't set up its environment yet. You can set it up by adding:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

at the top, but this is somewhat dirty. See if you can get away with moving the list comprehension to the `__init__`:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        self.list_display = [
            field.name for field in Person._meta.get_fields()
            if not field.primary_key
        ]
        super().__init__(model, admin_site)
```

**EDIT**: To accommodate the Eclipse introspection errors you can use `getattr` to explicitly tell it that it's a runtime thing:

```
self.list_display = [
    field.name for field in getattr(Person, '_meta').get_fields()
    if not field.primary_key
]
```

Comment: It still says undefined variable for _meta. class Person(models.Model) is in models.py is my data table.

Comment: I am coding in Eclipse. _.meta is underlined with red. when I move my cursor I get : "Undefined variable from import:_meta". Not sure how I could take the error output.

Comment: @PubuduGoonetilleke this is most likely is safe to ignore. It only gets created in the run-time, so your code should work just fine

Comment: Also, consider switching to the PyCharm IDE. It should be smarter about these things.